# HtmlHelper.Encode() an encoded quote

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to encode an already encoded string. The encoded quotes '&quot;' is not getting encoded to '&amp;quot;' when using HtmlHelper.encode() method().

Is there a way I can double encode all the characters?

For example:

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;     src=&quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt;
```

becomes

```
&amp;lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;     src=&quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js&quot;&amp;gt;
```

when I want

```
&amp;lt;script type=&amp;quot;text/javascript&amp;quot;     src=&amp;quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
```

Comment: After econding, I replaced the string occurrences of '&quot;' with '&amp;quot;'

Comment: No need for that... look at my answer below. It does the trick! :)

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai Is the behvior intended? Will double encoding cause &amp;lt; to &amp;amp;lt;

Comment: Nope. It will output exactly as you described above. I just tried it in an ASP.NET Web Form

Answer (score 0):

Encode twice:

`Server.HtmlEncode(Server.HtmlEncode(@"&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;"))`

I just tried this and it output what you wanted:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(Server.HtmlEncode(@"&lt;scripttype=&quot;text/javascript&quot;")));
}
```

Output came out:

```
&amp;lt;script type=&amp;quot;text/javascript&amp;quot;
```